# JavaScript array from user input sent to different page of site?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i saw this guy who had unanswered question on this site and i have been trying for the past hour to make his code work. as an amateur myself i cant seem to make the code work. the idea of the code is for you to be able to make a username and password on one page of the site. then it will send it as an array over to another page where it is processed as a log in. as i said i am an amateur and deep simple detail would be grate. thank you!

here is the page where the username and passwords are made:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
create account
</title>


<script>

function createLogIn() {
var usernameArray = document.getElementById("usernameMake").value;
var paswordArray = document.getElementById("pwordMake").value;
var unArray = []
var pwArray = []



localStorage.setItem("unArray", JSON.stringify([]));
localStorage.setItem("pwArray", JSON.stringify([]));

unArray.push("usernameArray");
pwArray.push("paswordArray");

}
</script>


</head>

<body>

<form name = "makeLogIn">
  <p class="log_on">
    ENTER YOUR NEW USERNAME <input type="text" id="usernameMake"><br><br><br><br><br>
    ENTER YOUR NEW PASSWORD <input type="text" id="pwordMake">
    <input type="button" value="create it" id="Submit" onclick="createLogIn">
  </p>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

here is where the username and password that were just created are used to log in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
log on page
</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var count = 2;

function validate() {
    var un = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var pw = document.getElementById("pword").value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("unArray"));
    var pwArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("pwArray"));

    for (var i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
    }

    var t = " tries";

    if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

    if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password. " +
               "You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
    }

    else {
        alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
        document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}
</script>

    <style>

    p.log_on{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
</style>





</head>


<body>

<form name = "myform">
  <p class="log_on">
    ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" id="username"><br><br><br><br><br>
    ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" id="pword">
    <input type="button" value="Check In" id="Submit" onclick="validate()">
  </p>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: The first issue is that the first page doesn't have any code that executes to take a user to the second page. On the second page - the validate() function never gets called to test anything that would be sent from the first page. Another issue - where are valid usernames and passwords coming from? Since JS is executed client side in web, you'd have to expose all the username/ password combos to the client which is horrible practice.

Answer (score 0):

So you need a few things to make this happen - and there are a million ways to skin this cat.

The most simple example I can provide is using basic POST request from a form - sending that data to a form processor. The steps work as follows:

1. Provide a form where we can get the username and passwords input
2. Send that data to a processor for validation
3. Redirect back to the original form if the logins are invalid or on to a another page if the validation passes.

And for your validate.php file:

```
<?php

$password = $_POST['password']; // gets password field passed from previous page
$username = $_POST['username']; // gets username passed from previous page

if($username == 'bob' && $password == 'bobs password') {
// do whatever you want to here in the case they got it right
echo 'Username & Password are CORRECT';
} else {
// do whatever you want to do if it's wrong
header('Location:http://mywebsite.com/login.html');
}

?>
```

Comment: i know JavaScript fairly well but i don't know PHP at all if you could give me corrections in JavaScript i would really appreciate that!

Comment: Because of security implications - solving it with a pure JS solution is not a viable solution for any production environment. You'd have to expose all usernames/passwords to the client side browser which is bad. I'd suggest not trying to use a hammer on a screw - you're best bet is learn a server side language to implement viable solutions in conjunction with front end technologies.

Comment: your right i think i will. any suggestions on a quick easy one to learn.

Comment: PHP is open source and very well documented. Supported on pretty much any stack - LAMP, WAMP, etc. http://php.net/manual/en